# Ignoring offers to coroutine channels after closing

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there a good way to have channels ignore offers once closed without throwing an exception?

Currently, it seems like only try catch would work, as `isClosedForSend` isn't atomic.

Alternatively, is there a problem if I just never close a channel at all?
For my specific use case, I'm using channels as an alternative to Android livedata (as I don't need any of the benefits beyond sending values from any thread and listening from the main thread). In that case, I could listen to the channel through a producer that only sends values when I want to, and simply ignore all other inputs.

Ideally, I'd have a solution where the `ReceiveChannel` can still finish listening, but where `SendChannel` will never crash when offered a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels throw this exception [by design](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/send.html), as means of correct communication.

If you absolutely must have something like this, you can use an extension function of this sort:

```
private suspend fun <E> Channel<E>.sendOrNothing(e: E) {
    try {
        this.send(e)
    }
    catch (closedException: ClosedSendChannelException) {
        println("It's fine")
    }
}
```

You can test it with the following piece of code:

```
val channel = Channel<Int>(capacity = 3)
    launch {

        try {
            for (i in 1..10) {
                channel.sendOrNothing(i)
                delay(50)
                if (i == 5) {
                    channel.close()
                }
            }

            println("Done")
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        finally {
            println("Finally")
        }
    }

    launch {
        for (c in channel) {
            println(c)
            delay(300)
        }
    }
```

As you'll notice, producer will start printing "It's fine" since the channel is closed, but consumer will still be able to read first 5 values.

Regarding your second question: it depends.

Channels don't have such a big overhead, and neither do suspended coroutines. But a leak is a leak, you know.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up being redirected to post [an issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/937) in the github repo, and the solution was to use `BroadcastChannel` to imitate something like `PublishSubject`. Leak wise, it'll only be a boolean or int not associated with the ui so it should probably be fine

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting [an issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/937) to the repo, and the solution was to use `BroadcastChannel`. You can create a new `ReceiveChannel` through `openSubscription`, where closing it will not close the `SendChannel`.

This more accurately reflects RxJava's `PublishSubject`